# Ways and Vertices tables empty after osm2pgrouting tutorial

Tags: postgis, references, osm2pgrouting

I've been following the osm2pgrouting tutorial, have compiled osm2pgrouting with necessary boost and expat libs installed, and built a postgresql db with support for postgis and pgrouting.

Importing the osm2pgrouting sample data appears to work in the terminal, and after import the 'classes', 'nodes', and 'types' tables look fine, but 'ways' table is empty and there are no vertices_ tables.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then I tried to add the optional parameter -host specifing the 127.0.0.1 address.
Everything went well for me.

It's just a suggestion but I think could work..

regards

Lorenzo