# osm2pgrouting tables emtpy

Tags: postgis, osm2pgrouting, postgresql-9.5

When I use the osm2pgrouting I only get emtpy tables.

I got my .osm file from this [Wien.os.gz](http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Wien/) and use the mapconfig.xml from [Github](https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting).

I run the follwing command:

```
./osm2pgrouting -f path/Wien.osm -c path/conf.xml -d osm2 -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -W user --clean
```

I added the

```
 -h 127.0.0.1
```

according to this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21610/ways-and-vertices-tables-empty-after-osm2pgrouting-tutorial), but it didn´t help.

This is the output I get:
[image]

Any ideas why this doesn´t work..

Comment: I was able to import the *.osm*-extract from the *Wien.osm.bz* file with *osm2pgrouting* and the *mapconfig.xml* file that came both shipped with OSGeo PostgreSQL/PostGIS installation. could you add your PostGIS and *osm2pgrouting* versions?

Comment: I work with OSGeo Live 11.0 , osm2pgrouting version 2.2; PostGIS 2.3.2

Comment: do you have pgRouting enabled on the DB?

Comment: Yes, version 2.4.1